# PySpark performance chained transformations vs successive reassignment

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm somewhat new to PySpark.  I understand that it uses lazy evaluation, meaning that execution of a series of transformations will be deferred until some action is requested, at which point the Spark engine optimizes the entire set of transformations and then executes them.

Therefore, from both functional and performance standpoint I would expect this:

*Approach A*

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(path) 
df = df.filter(F.col('state') == 'CA')
df = df.select('id', 'name', 'subject')
df = df.groupBy('subject').count()
```

to be the same as this:

*Approach B*

```py
df = spark.read.parquet(path)\
    .filter(F.col('state') == 'CA')\
    .select('id', 'name', 'subject')\
    .groupBy('subject').count()
```

I like the style of *Approach A* because it would allow me to break up my logic into smaller (and re-usable) functions.

However, I have come across a few blog posts (e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@rakeshchanda25/pyspark-performance-optimization-97e4a4fc85cc), [here](https://medium.com/@davisjustin42/pyspark-remove-chaining-withcolumn-calls-279fbb4af38) and [here](https://www.aizoo.info/post/just-one-more-column-what-could-go-wrong)) that are confusing to me.  These posts deal specifically with the use of successive `withColumn` statements and suggest using a single `select` instead.  The underlying rationale seems to be that since dataframes are immutable, successive `withColumn` usage is detrimental to performance.

So my question is... would I have that same performance issue when using *Approach A*?  Or is it just an issue specific to `withColumn`?

Comment: Updated answer, same applies. Try it.

Comment: Strictly speaking I answered the question. You actually have 2 questions here at diverging angles.

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry I didn't understand "You actually have 2 questions here at diverging angles.".  What do you mean by "diverging angles"?  Is there some additional information I can provide that would help clarify the question?

Comment: Its ok. I will further address the question later.

Comment: Added to the answer. The 2nd answer in fact,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 questions in fact.

**First question with codes samples.**
Unlike the 1st answer I disagree.

Try both code segments with an `.explain()` and you will see the generated Physical Plan for Execution is *exactly the same*.

Spark is based on `lazy evaluation`. That is to say:

> All transformations in Spark are lazy, in that they do not compute
> their results right away. Instead, they just remember the
> transformations applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). The
> transformations are only computed when an action requires a result to
> be returned to the driver program. This design enables Spark to run
> more efficiently. For example, we can realize that a dataset created
> through map will be used in a reduce and return only the result of the
> reduce to the driver, rather than the larger mapped dataset.

The upshot of all this is, that I ran similar code to yours with 2 filters applied, and note that as the **Action** `.count` causes just-in-time evaluation, Catalyst filtered out based on both the first and the 2nd filter. This is known as `"Code Fusing"` - which can be done to late execution aka Lazy Evaluation.

**Snippet 1 and Physical Plan**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)

df = df.filter(col('lastname') == 'Jones')
df = df.select('firstname', 'lastname', 'salary')
df = df.filter(col('lastname') == 'Jones2')
df = df.groupBy('lastname').count().explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[lastname#212], functions=[finalmerge_count(merge count#233L) AS count(1)#228L])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(lastname#212, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=391]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[lastname#212], functions=[partial_count(1) AS count#233L])
         +- Project [lastname#212]
            +- Filter (isnotnull(lastname#212) AND ((lastname#212 = Jones) AND (lastname#212 = Jones2)))
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[firstname#210,middlename#211,lastname#212,id#213,gender#214,salary#215]
```

**Snippet 2 and Same Physical Plan**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
data2 = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]

schema2 = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])
 
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema2)

df2 = df2.filter(col('lastname') == 'Jones')\
       .select('firstname', 'lastname', 'salary')\
       .filter(col('lastname') == 'Jones2')\
       .groupBy('lastname').count().explain()

== Physical Plan ==
AdaptiveSparkPlan isFinalPlan=false
+- HashAggregate(keys=[lastname#299], functions=[finalmerge_count(merge count#320L) AS count(1)#315L])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(lastname#299, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=577]
      +- HashAggregate(keys=[lastname#299], functions=[partial_count(1) AS count#320L])
         +- Project [lastname#299]
            +- Filter (isnotnull(lastname#299) AND ((lastname#299 = Jones) AND (lastname#299 = Jones2)))
               +- Scan ExistingRDD[firstname#297,middlename#298,lastname#299,id#300,gender#301,salary#302]
```

**Second Question - withColumn**

Doing this:

```
df = df.filter(col('lastname') == 'Jones')
df = df.select('firstname', 'lastname', 'salary')
df = df.withColumn("salary100",col("salary")*100) 
df = df.withColumn("salary200",col("salary")*200).explain()
```

or via chaining gives the same result as well. I.e. it does not matter how you write the transformations. The final Physical Plan is what counts, but that *optimization has overhead though*. Depends how you think on this, `select` is the alternative.

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [firstname#399, lastname#401, salary#404, (salary#404 * 100) AS salary100#414, (salary#404 * 200) AS salary200#419]
+- *(1) Filter (isnotnull(lastname#401) AND (lastname#401 = Jones))
   +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[firstname#399,middlename#400,lastname#401,id#402,gender#403,salary#404]
```

This article [https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015#:~:text=Summary,number%20of%20transforms%20on%20DataFrame%20](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015#:%7E:text=Summary,number%20of%20transforms%20on%20DataFrame%20) takes a different perspective on the cost of optimization as opposed to 'projection' issue. I am, was surprized that 3 withColumns would cause any issue. If it is an issue then it points to crap optimization. And I suspect that looping of many features is the real issue, not a small number of withColumns.

Comment: thank you for providing an explanation and supporting information.  Your answer is what I would have expected from my understanding of what lazy evaluation is.  What about the specific case of using `withColumn`?  Do successive `withColumn` statements have worse performance than a single `select` statement?

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail w.r.t. `withColumn`.  So it seems like the tl;dr is: 1) chaining vs successive re-assignment doesn't make a difference; 2) for transformations on multiple columns, doing them individually using `withColumn` incurs a slight additional overhead for optimization, though you'd have to be doing a lot of these for it to make a material difference; 3) the two concepts of #1 and #2 are orthogonal (I guess this is what you meant in your comment about "diverging angles", I understand now).

Comment: @teejay  you got. Spark has still some improvements to make as well. the explains are hard to read as well as the UI output. Success

Answer (score 0):

**Approach A:**

- In this approach, each line creates a new DataFrame, and the previous
  DataFrame is replaced with the new one.
- This can lead to performance issues, especially with large datasets,
  due to the overhead of DataFrame creation and management
- Successive withColumn statements can lead to performance issues in
  PySpark due to the immutability of DataFrames.

**Approach B:**

- Instead of using successive withColumn statements, you can use a
  single select statement to achieve the same result.
- It performs the transformations in a single pass through the data.
- Each operation in the chain is applied directly to the DataFrame
  returned by the preceding operation without creating intermediate
  DataFrames.

Approach B is typically preferred for its better performance and cleaner, more concise code.

Comment: Performance is equal.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have the following questions:

1. Performance difference between not chaining the operations (Approach A in your question) vs chaining the operations (Approach B in your question)?
2. Performance difference between multiple `withColumn()` statements vs a single `select()` statement?

Now answering the 2nd question is quite straightforward. As noted in the spark API reference for [`withColumn()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html#:%7E:text=or%20replaced%20column.-,Notes,-This%20method%20introduces):

> This method introduces a projection internally. Therefore, calling it multiple times, for instance, via loops in order to add multiple columns can generate big plans which can cause performance issues and even *StackOverflowException*. To avoid this, use [`select()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select) with multiple columns at once.

I hope this makes it clear that in certain situations (for eg. loops) there can be a performance difference between `withColumn()` and `select()` and it's better to use the latter in general. You can read more on the hidden cost of `withColumn()` [here](https://medium.com/@manuzhang/the-hidden-cost-of-spark-withcolumn-8ffea517c015).

Finally, coming to the 1st question:  Short answer - Nope, there is no (negligible if any) performance difference between the two approaches.

Maybe (correct me if I am wrong) your doubt is arising from the fact that not chaining the dataframe operations and using them separately is creating multiple intermediary dataframes which might be causing an overhead **but** the exact thing is happening while chaining as well. Therefore, they have the same physical plans and performance with negligible differences if any.

So, the only difference that remains is readability.