Huge time gap between spark jobs, query optimization taking 90% of job time
I have one application in which i am adding 500+ columns using withColumn.
All are fairly complex transformations. I am computing each attribute and adding to my DF one by one.
i have put all 500 code and at the end i am doing df.persist().count() to evaluate all the stuff and have all computation done before i write it to my hive table.
Problem is it takes 10-15 min to read and process all 500 attributes (To reach till df.count).
Then the spark waits for around 1 hour 30 min sometimes 2 hr+. There is no trace on sparkui what is happening here.
Then after that i see it runs and computes count and writes to table which completes in next 10-15 minutes.
Can someone explain what's happening in middle 2 hour? and how can i trace/fix or reduce this.
I thought of replacing few withColumn as it is costly to selectexpr but that wont work out in my case because all 500 attribute are interconnected so i might need to recall or recompute each attribute again and again using selectexpr i was getting ambigious col error.
EDIT 1:
One eg of 1 attribute pseducode is like
#adding 7 attributes needed for abc
        df=calling7function().retrieve(self.spark, self.context_dict)

        df=df.withColumn("abc",
            F.when((df.x=='Y'), 'OS') \
            .when((df.t=='Y'), 'SR') \
            .when((df.a=='Y'), '3F') \
            .when((df.v=='Y'), 'SS') \
            .when((df.w=='Y'), 'DL') \
            .when((df.v=='Y'), 'RO') \
            .when((df.wq=='Y'), 'RS') \
            .when((df.as=='Y'), 'CO') \
            .otherwise('')
        )
        #updating it
        df=df.withColumn("abc",
            F.when((df.asd.isNotNull()) & (df.abc=='') & (df.rsx.isin(['6','7','9'])), 'RS') \
            .when((df.asd.isNotNull()) & (df.abc=='') & (df.rsx=='1'), 'CO') \
            .when((df.asd.isNotNull()) & (df.abc=='') & (df.rsx=='13'), 'SS') \
            .when((df.asd.isNotNull()) & (df.abc=='') & (df.rsx=='14'), '3F').otherwise(df.abc))
        
        df=df.withColumn("abc",F.when((df.ax=='qq') & (df.aq=='OOO'), 'RO').when((df.ae=='we') & (df.qwe=='OOO'), 'RS').otherwise(df.abc))

        df=df.withColumn("abc",F.when((df.abc=='') , 'PO').otherwise(df.abc))


It would be good.. if you can post your code so that anyone one can guide you.

as you note withColumn is expensive - it's likely the reason you have this issue.  Replace that with a single call to withColumns instead

Will clubbing them under withColumns help the performance? how does withColumns works internally?

df.count() doesn't materialize the dataframe. So most likely the 2 hr is actually where the actual transformation is taking place. To see this, materialize the dataframe with. df.cache.foreach(lambda x: x) and then   df.count(), now the count won't printed immediately. Having long lineage of transformations slows down final evaluation so it takes more time. After every Nth transformation (N = 3 or 4 or 5 etc, play with value) materialize the dataframe. Try this workaround if it works.

df.count is not free it has to evaluate a large portion of the dataset, it's not going to be the same plan as writing data.  @DeveshSingh - withColumns performs something like a single action and then a single select on constructed columns, straight select is faster still but for your code it should be an easy change.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78241781/pyspark-performance-chained-transformations-vs-successive-reassignment/78243739#78243739

Per the comment above and your note in the question - don't use withColumn in this way if you want performance.  For the columns which truly depend on other columns you are adding you must add them in a second projection.
All withColumns does is check existing column names to identify if fields should be dropped, modified or added for you, to do this it must perform an action (e.g. reading the files to get a schema).  In your case of interdependent fields this could be an impact performance wise as you'd need to do multiple withColumns.
If you know all of the fields anyway use multiple selects (not selectExpr as you note) for each collection of fields which can stand alone - it won't work if you have fields which depend on each other (probably causing your ambiguous col error).  withColumns does it's action and then calls select anyway so you can skip this cost.
Note that evaluating performance with count is, at best, a hint, Spark chooses  different plans based on the action it's taking, you should measure with the exact action you intend to use (e.g. if you are writing files out, then you should test with file writes).

Yes this is helpful for the understanding. but in my case it was tough to implement select instead of withColumn to maintain modularity of the code. the problem is no 100% solved, but i used checkpoint and just before that i stopped using df.count() and used df.rdd.foreachPartition(lambda _: None) which gave me around 20-30% improvement.
basically spark optimization was taking longer time than when i started forceful evaluation after every x transformations
