What happens to the dataframe in spark when it gets transformed into a new dataframe?
I am a beginner in Apache Spark. I'm having trouble learning about Spark. As far as I know, Spark works based on Lazy Evaluation and dataframes in Spark are immutable.
I have a dataframe df with 3 columns songay_xuly, loai_ngay and ma. If I transform
df = df.withColumn("day", col("songay_xuly").cast("int"))

will create a new dataframe, will the two columns songay_xuly and ma point to the old df or will they be duplicated data from old data?
Thanks in advance!
Looking forward to receiving answers from anyone!

Spark won't execute until you invoke the action on the dataframe. Until then, it will construct the DAG contains all transformations. also your data will not be duplicated.

So if 1 dataframe has 100 transformations and calls to 1 action, there will be 100 completely different dataframes created, right? Thus, if 1 dataframe contains 10G, it will create 1000G of data. Am I understanding this wrong?

nope. only 1 dataframe with all transformations & size will be same 10G ( depends on transformations.. if you have explode then size might be more)

I still don't understand, please explain in detail.

Leaving action aspect aside, if you chain 3 withColumns and don't do a break lineage via .checkpoint, the withColumns will be fused and you will have for lineage the immutable old dataframe and this new dataframe.
The peformance of withColumn is not optimal, so use of select is often better. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78243739/1028537.

df = df.withColumn("day", col("songay_xuly").cast("int"))

introduces a new dataframe with an additional (or replaced) column 'day', based on songay_xuly.  If day existed before in df, it will no longer be selected, in many cases this means the data won't be read from the underlying data source.
The previous field songay_xuly is still there in df and occupies a different place in memory - but only when the action is run.
Spark sql is a program that you build up in the dsl (or sql text) that only runs when the action is taken.  Until then it's a lightweight representation of what should happen.
from your comment I'll break it into two questions:

So if 1 dataframe has 100 transformations and calls to 1 action, there will be 100 completely different dataframes created, right?

It depends on how those transformation are made, per thebluephantom's answer if you use 100 withColumn calls you'll get 100 programs that can be run - but good luck in it ever running due to performance issues. If you do 100 transformations in a single select (ie. all new fields or based on existing fields) then you'll only create 1 extra program.
Note - program - not data.

Thus, if 1 dataframe contains 10G, it will create 1000G of data. Am I understanding this wrong?

Hopefully from the above answer you can see it's at worst 100 programs you've created and that 10g is never "read" or "created", when you run that action it's the current program that is run, none of the other 99 will do anything.
If you are familiar with SQL databases you can think of the spark api as building the SQL string and only when you ask the backend database to execute does the data get read.
That said, again per thebluephantom's answer, if you use withColumn 100 times your performance will be horrendous irrespective of your data volumes.
In short, aside from withColumn usage, concentrate on the correct logic in your dataset/frame usage when creating that program and let spark figure out how to run it, its typically very good at that.
caveats: actions can take multiple forms, withColumn itself can trigger an action to read the input files for schema information, this can be extremely expensive (e.g. merge schema on adls parquet).  If you know your schema and can use select style projections you should prefer it.
